# iCloud Drive shows up empty in Finder after logging out

Tags: icloud, finder

Some of my files and in my Macbook Pro 2015 were showing a dotted iCloud icon with an exclamation mark inside them, which, if my memory serves me right, means that I am out of iCloud storage. The thing is, I just bought 50GB of iCloud storage and all the files in my Desktop only amounts to more or less 12GB and I still had around 45GB left.

But that's not the problem right now. The thing is, I saw a suggestion online that told me to try to Sign Out of iCloud, shut down my Macbook, then Sign In again to fix the problem I mentioned above. However, that brought a problem of its own. When I checked my iCloud drive in Finder, it shows that I have nothing in my iCloud drive. I already checked my iCloud drive using my iPad and I am confident that they are still there.

Now then, how do I make my files appear? Can I do anything or is my only option to wait it out?

Answer (score 3):

iCloud Drive takes a while to initialize. A loong while. Do not worry, so long as the files appear on [iCloud.com](https://www.icloud.com) they will be downloaded. This may take over 24 hours unfortunately and it won't appear to be doing anything at all. Leave your computer on and connected to the internet and wait it out.